# Why does GetExitCodeThread() return FALSE here?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, mfc

I have a small test code. My assumption is in below code, since I didn't set flag to stop the thread, then in the line of `GetExitCodeThread()`. it should return `TRUE` and return code is `STILL_ACTIVE`.
While in actual test, the result is:
Every time, the return value of `GetExitCodeThread()` is `FALSE`, so in `main()`, the `while` loop never entered. Could somebody please tell me the reason? What's wrong in my code. Thanks.

```
// ConsoleApplication1.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "afxwin.h"

bool bExit = false;
HANDLE hOriginalThread;

static UINT ThreadFunc(LPVOID pParam)
{
    int iCount = 0;
    printf("start thread--ThreadFunc\n");
    printf("Thread loop start: --ThreadFunc");
    while (!bExit)
    {
        iCount++;
        if (iCount % 50 == 0)
            printf(".");
    }
    printf("Thread loop end: %d--ThreadFunc\n", iCount++);
    printf("end thread--ThreadFunc\n");
    return 0;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    hOriginalThread = AfxBeginThread(ThreadFunc, (LPVOID)0, THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL, 0, 0);
    Sleep(500);
    DWORD dwEC;
    int iTry = 0;
    BOOL bStatus;
    bStatus = GetExitCodeThread(hOriginalThread, &dwEC);
    if (!bStatus)
    {
        printf("error GetExitCodeThread: %d--Main\n", GetLastError());
    }
    while (bStatus && dwEC == STILL_ACTIVE)
    {
        printf("Check Thread in active: %d--Main\n", iTry);
        Sleep(1);
        iTry++;
        if (iTry>5)
        {
            printf("Try to terminate Thread loop: %d--Main\n", iTry++);
            TerminateThread(hOriginalThread, 0);// Force thread exit
        }
        bStatus = GetExitCodeThread(hOriginalThread, &dwEC);
    }
    hThread = NULL;
    printf("End Main --Main\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

[`AfxBeginThread()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/application-information-and-management?view=vs-2019#afxbeginthread) returns a [`CWinThread*`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwinthread-class?view=vs-2019) object pointer, not a Win32 `HANDLE` like [`CreateThread()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createthread) does. So `GetExitCodeThread()` fails due to an invalid thread handle, which `GetLastError()` should have told you.

`CWinThread` has an [`operator HANDLE()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwinthread-class?view=vs-2019#operator_handle) to get the proper Win32 handle of the thread, eg:

```
CWinThread *pThread = AfxBeginThread(...);
if (!pThread) ... // error handling
hOriginalThread = *pThread;
```

The reason your code even compiles is because you are likely not compiling with [STRICT Type Checking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/strict-type-checking) enabled, so `HANDLE` is just a simple `void*`, which *any* kind of pointer can be assigned to. If you enable STRICT, `HANDLE` will not be `void*` and assigning the return value of `AfxBeginThread()` directly to `hOriginalThread` will cause a compiler error due to a type incompatibility.